# Family of sets written with dual indices has what meaning?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, index-notation, outer-measure

I was reading the proposition

> Let ${A_n}$ be a countable collection of sets of real numbers. Then
>   $m^*(\cup A_n)\leq \sum m^*(A_n)$.

Proof: fix $\epsilon >0$ and for every n choose a set of open
 intervals $\{I_m^n\}_{m=1}^\infty$ that cover $A_n$ and such that
 $\sum_m l({I_m^n}) \leq m^*(A_n) - \frac{\epsilon}{2^n}$...

What does the notation with dual indexes $n$ and $m$ of $\{I_m^n\}_{m=1}^\infty$? mean?

I think it means, for every set $A_n$, there is a corresponding $I_n$ and in total there are $m$ open intervals $I_n$ that whose union cover $A_n$?

The set with these $m$ numbered from one to infinity open intervals $I_n$ is $\{I_m^n\}_{m=1}^\infty$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to remember for the remainder of the proof that the the $I^n_m$ "belong to" $A_n$, the $m$ is just the index of the countable family of intervals. $I(n)_m$ would have been just as valid, or some other notation. You can do it for each fixed $n$ and for that $n$ we call the intervals $I^n_m$, where $m=1,2,3,\ldots$ etc.

Of course, in total we are choosing countably many such intervals, as a countable union of countable sets is still countable, and all of them together can now be denoted $\{I^n_m: n,m \in \Bbb N\}$, e.g.

Comment: Would drawing a picture explain better what's the relationship between $m, n$ $I_n, A$, $\{I_m^n\}_{m=1}^\infty$ etc?

Comment: @Numbers No, not really. You just apply the definitions..

Comment: What's the difference between $I(n)_m$ and $I_n$ or $\{I_n\}$ where $I_n$ where $I_n$ is some interval?

Comment: @Numbers whatever you want it to mean. It's an introduced notation, not a fixed one. The intervals depend on $n$, and the author wants to express that. You could also use $I(n)_m$ as well as $I^n_m$ for the same idea.

Comment: How to express $\{I^n_m: n,m \in \Bbb N\}$ in union notation?

Comment: @Numbers The union of them can be written in several equivalent ways: $$\bigcup_{n,m=1}^{\infty} I^n_m = \bigcup_{m=1}^\infty \bigcup _{n=1}^\infty I^n_m = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup _{m=1}^\infty I^n_m$$ etc.